# What can you do in WinAPI that you cannot do in Qt?

Tags: qt, winapi

I am into learning some GUI API in C++, so I searched a lot to see which one was best. I ended up with either Qt or WinAPI. I read some people saying that Qt was easier to work with but with WinAPI you could control everything. The argument proceeded and someone said that it was a fair exchange, a small piece of control so it could become easier. Now I want to know, what exactly are you losing when you chose Qt? Is it the interaction with the system? What exactly can you do in WinAPI that you cannot do in Qt?

Comment: If you want to control everything, use WinAPI. If you want to get anything done, use Qt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing apples and oranges here.  Qt is a C++ class library designed to help you implement a GUI and is cross-platform, you can recompile your code to run on different operating systems.  The winapi is the low-level C-based api to make operating system calls on Windows.  You *can* create a GUI app using only the winapi, Charles Petzold shows you how, but it is quite a punishing approach to developing such an app.  A "Hello world" app using only the winapi is an easy hundred lines of code.

Don't contemplate using only the winapi to implement a GUI, you'll deeply regret it after spending several months learning how to get it right.  There are many tools to simplify that job, Qt is just one of them and it isn't limited to just the C++ language.  Of course, the fact that Qt is cross-platform *does* mean that certain Windows' specific features are poorly or not at all directly supported in Qt.  You do however have the option to fall back to the winapi if you need it.  At the cost of giving up cross-platform support.

Answer (score 3):

The most "heavy weight" things Qt looses are the Shell API, the DWM and the Ribbon UI. There are more, like the compression API.

However, it is fairly easy to write your own Qt style interfaces to those APIs.

Best regards